# Relation between normal matrices of matrix Lie algebras and their Cartan subalgebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

***Math question***: Let $\phi = \phi_A X^A \in \mathfrak g$ where $\phi_A \in \mathbb C$ for all $A =1,\cdots, \dim \mathfrak g$, and $X^A$ form a basis of some semi-simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ over $\mathbb C$. Here we are viewing $\phi_A$ to be a vector transforming in the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak g$ with $X^A$ being some matrices in the defining representation (that is, matrices which define $\mathfrak g$ as a linear, matrix Lie algebra). Also, by $\phi^{\dagger}$ we mean the complex conjugate transpose of $\phi$. Prove, if $[\phi, \phi^{\dagger}] = 0$, then $\phi$ must be an element of a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$, where $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is the standard Lie bracket i.e. commutator on $\mathfrak g$.

***Physics context***: when studying the moduli space of vacua of $4d$ $\mathcal N=2$ supersymmetric gauge theories which possess a Lagrangian, i.e. $4d$ $\mathcal N=2$ SUSY Yang-Mills theories with some gauge group $\mathfrak g$, the component of the space of vacua called the Coulomb branch is defined (at least classically) by solutions to the equation $[\phi, \phi^{\dagger}]=0$ where $\phi_{A} (\phi)$ is an adjoint (matrix)- valued complex scalar field operator from the $4d$ $\mathcal N=2$ vector multiplet. It should be understood I am abusing notation a bit and should really replace $\phi_A \to \langle \phi_A \rangle \in \mathbb C$ in the above equation to denote the vacuum expectation value of the field operator $\phi_A$, but this is usually understood in physics contexts so that the above equation makes sense. See [this OG paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9407087.pdf), pg. 7-8 for example.

***Solution 1***: $[\phi, \phi^{\dagger}]=0$ implies $\phi$ is a normal matrix and therefore is diagonalizable. Then, it can be proven that diagonalizability of $\phi$ as a matrix implies $\phi$ is also ad-diagonalizable, see e.g, [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150272/show-that-the-eigenvalues-of-ada-adjoint-action-are-lambda-i-lambda-j) or [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464450/what-are-the-eigenvalues-of-operatornameadx?noredirect=1&lq=1). Finally, from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314046/does-semisimple-element-of-a-semisimple-complex-lie-algebra-belong-to-some-carta) question, we learn that if $\phi$ is ad-diagonalizable i.e. semi-simple, then it is contained in some Cartan subalgebra since, for semi-simple Lie algebras, the union of the CSA's equals the set of semi-simple elements of $\mathfrak g$.

***Solution 2***: At least when we are talking about the classical matrix Lie algebras $A_n, B_n, C_n, D_n$ over $\mathbb C$, since we can diagonalize $\phi$, it becomes a diagonal matrix. Then, according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968855/cartan-subalgebras-of-classical-lie-algebras-are-diagonal-matrices) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768129/root-space-decomposition-of-c-n-mathfraksp2n-f/3771729#3771729) answer we see that the set of diagonal matrices so defined in each of these respective Lie algebras forms a Cartan subalgebra, implying $\phi$, once diagonalized, is in this Cartan subalgebra. (For the physicists, we are allowed to diagonalize $\phi$ because this is a gauge transformation.)

These solutions seem a bit awkward/convoluted. Are there solutions which are faster requiring just basic Lie/linear algebra facts?

Comment: I don't think you can get more basic than what is your solution 1. That any semisimple element of a semisimple Lie algebra is contained in some CSA seems to be the crucial fact you'll need one way or another. Spelling it out with diagonal matrices might seem nicer but is actually less conceptual.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg you make a good point. I was hoping there might be some quick argument alongs the lines a choosing a basis (such as the Cartan-Weyl) and then showing the resulting matrix equations could not be satisfied unless the raising/lowering operators were zero. At any rate, your past answers were very helpful for both solutions!

Comment: Thanks. By the way, if one uses the alternative definition of CSAs (in e.g. complex semisimple LAs) that they are exactly the "maximal toral" ones (cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2497093/96384), then the fact that every semisimple element lies in such a CSA is nearly trivial. Of course now the work has been outsourced into the equivalence of that alternative definition to the more standard ones of CSAs.